# Renderizar view através do controller usando Slim Framework 3

Tags: php, slim

Estou tentando encontrar um jeito de renderizar a view usando um controller no `slim framework` mas por algum motivo estou recebendo o erro:

```
Message: Using $this when not in object context
```

A função é uma função publica e esta dentro de uma classe normalmente e estou seguindo o que diz na [Documentação](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html)

Minha rota:

```
$app->get('/home', '\App\Http\Controller\Teste::main');
```

O Controller base:

```
class Controller
{
   protected $ci;

   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $ci)
   {
       $this->ci = $ci;
   }
}
```

A classe de teste:

```
class Teste extends Controller
{
   public function index($request, $response)
   {
      return "Hello!"; // Funciona
   }

   public function main($request, $response)
   {
       var_dump($this->ci); // Apresenta o erro
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Já perdi muitas horas com um erro similar a esse. O problema está neste trecho:

```
$app->get('/home', '\App\Http\Controller\Teste::main');
```

Com o uso do "::" você está chamando um método estático. E por esse motivo o this não existe. Tente assim:

```
$app->get('/home', '\App\Http\Controller\Teste:main');
```